# Is it possible to use a bookmarklet to load and run Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, cross-domain, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet that loads Google Maps dynamically and displays it in a dialog overlay. It works fine when I run it on the same site (localhost in this case) that the bookmarklet JavaScript is loaded from, but not when I go to a third-party site like NYTimes.com for example. I don't see any HTTP errors in Firebug, but when the bookmarklet code tries to instantiate a new google.maps object, the console shows the following message:

```
TypeError: google.maps is undefined
```

Is what I'm attempting an illegal cross-domain call or might there be something wrong with my implementation?

This is the code that's loading the maps script from my bookmarklet bootloader:

```
var mapsScript = document.createElement("script");
mapsScript.type = "text/javascript";
mapsScript.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=KEY&sensor=true&callback=CALLBACK";
document.body.appendChild(mapsScript);
```

Later, the callback has the following line:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(la, ln);
```

Comment: Some code to look at would be nice :)

Comment: In one example I had this happen.  I had to do an onload() in the body for google maps.  This may or may not be your problem. Reference this and see if you are setting it right: research this: addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);  Also, what api version are you using? v3 I hope.

Comment: I'm loading as a bookmarklet, and as such, have to wait for the user to load the script so I can't grab the onload handler.

Comment: Oh yeah, and I'm using v3 api